# Divide or not to divide in a smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, gas, events, gas-price

I need my contract to create a ratio of two big integers (prices) output in an event. Which of two variants is better:

1. divide in the contract using a math library;
2. output two integers and let the offchain app divide (e.g. just by converting to two floating point values to make it easier to program)?

I think 2 is better because 1 uses extra gas for heavy division operation. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think number division is very expensive in Solidity, but not sure. Depending on your needs, I would be probably more worried about the precision: as there are no floating point numbers in Solidity a division is bound to lose some precision.

In any case, if at all possible, do it off-chain. Basically you should always do everything off-chain unless there is a reason to do it on-chain (such as trust issues). Division in off-chain is very trivial and memory/performance shouldn't be an issue.